# Neo4j : Query with relation filter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've to write one cypher for schema where all nodes are having multiple relations in between them.
So I want to filter the nodes lets say, first search nodes which have relation HELPSin between theme. Then on Check if those nodes also have KNOWSrelation in between them then return all nodes with all other relations(including HELPS & KNOWS). Right now to filter the relation I'm using below cypher:

```js
MATCH (a)-[r:HELPS]->(b)
WITH distinct a,b
MATCH (a)-[rs:KNOWS]-(b)
RETURN a,b LIMIT 25
```

Is there any provision to do so Like

```js
MATCH (a)-[r:HELPS AND KNOWS]->(b)
WITH DISTINCT a,b
path = (a)-[*]-(b) //To get all other relations in between filtered nodes.
RETURN rels(path),nodes(path)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i don't think there is any AND operation for this type of query

you can use

```
MATCH (a)-[:HELPS]->(b)-[:KNOWS]-(a)
WITH  DISTINCT a , b 
MATCH a-[r]-b
WHERE NOT type(r) IN ['HELPS', 'KNOWS']
RETURN r
```

Comment: And how about getting all (Other) relations  in between and b

Comment: @GovindMantri hmm!! need one match then again

Answer (score 2):

The below will get all other relations between a and b , apart from `helps` and `knows`.

```
    MATCH p = (b)<-[KNOWS]-(a)-[HELPS]->(b) 
    WITH a,b
    MATCH a-[r]->b
    WHERE NOT type(r) IN ['HELPS', 'KNOWS']
    RETURN r
```

Comment: It will not give all other relation if A & B are not consecutive nodes ie. 
A->B->C->D->E

Comment: you asked other relations between a and b as per the question and comment@GovindMantri

Comment: you can always modify the answer according to your needs.. if you dont want the relationship directional you can use a-[r]-b in the second match case

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that one in above query!! my scenario is :
It will not give all other relation if A & B are not consecutive nodes ie. 
A->B->C->D->E then I want to get all relations (paths) from A-D using that common relation which can be HELPS/KNOWS